# Selecting parts of an expression via mouse clicks

Tags: front-end, text, keyboard

Is there a ***very easy*** way to select (=highlight)

```
FunC[FunD[FunE[x]]]
```

in the following code?

```
FunA[FunB[FunC[FunD[FunE[x]]]]]
```

Comment: See the [Selecting and Typing](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/SelectingAndTypingInNotebooks.html) Guide in the documentation. Further clicking beyond the third click also continues to expand the selection as well.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, put the cursor on FunC

[image]

and ***triple click*** your left mouse button.